# How can i change the background color of my toast

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have added a toast in my project using the below code in my `newrecord.ts`

```
constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private _listProduct : ListproductService,
    private _deleteProduct : DeleteProductService,
    public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams: NavParams,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    private datePipe: DatePipe) {
        this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
                            content: 'Please wait...'
                        });

        this.mytoast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                            message: 'Data loaded successfully',
                            duration: 3000,
                            position: 'top'
                        });

        this.initializeItems();
}
```

and inside `ngOnInit()` I have called my toast like this `this.mytoast.present();`

It is working perfectly fine but instead of black can I use any other background color for my toast?

> I have read cssClass property but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define another background color by overriding a `Ionic Sass Variables` in your `variables.scss`

In case of `toast` background you could define for example `white` or `#ffffff` like following:

```
$toast-ios-background: #ffffff; // Apply for iOS
$toast-md-background: #ffffff; // Apply for Android
$toast-wp-background: white; // Apply for Windows
```

You could find the all list of sass variables you could override in the documentation:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

In case you would like even more flexibility or to set other styles, you could set a `custom css property` to your toast with the `cssClass` option

For example:

```
 this.mytoast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                        message: 'Data loaded successfully',
                        duration: 3000,
                        position: 'top',
                        cssClass: 'myCustomCss'
                    });
```

Then you could modify it in your stylesheets, like in `app.component.scss`

```
.myCustomCss {
    // The styles you would like to apply
 }
```

See `ToastController` API documentation:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toast/ToastController/

But when it goes to the background of the toast, first try with the variables ;)

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Please vote for my question if it looks suitable to you